# Removing unwanted characters from name tag with php

Tags: php

I have the following code snippet:

```
echo "<label><input type='checkbox'  class='selector' name='{$data['ColA']}'>" .preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $data['ColA'])."</label>";
```

Here I'd like to use `preg_replace` in "`name`" tag as well. How can I make it work? I tried the same code in name tag but it doesn't work. Thanks.

The output of this code is like this:

```
 <label>
        <input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='7b'>7</label>
```

I need to remove "b" from 7 in name tag too.

Comment: Can you show what you tried for the name attribute?

Comment: `name='{preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $data['ColA'])}` and this: `name='{.preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $data['ColA']).}`

Comment: Remove the `{}`s those are so the array prints in the double quotes. Just concatenate the function call, like you did on the other

Comment: `name= ".preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $data['ColA'])."` ok, this worked. thanks a lot! if you post your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using functions inside of this syntax with `{}` is not really a good idea and may lead to some issues you can avoid in the most simple way, just terminate the string, concatenate it with your function output and the rest of the string, like so:

```
echo "<label><input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='" . preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $data['ColA']) . "'>" . preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $data['ColA'])."</label>";
```

So in general:

```
echo "Something: " . a_function($variable) . ", the rest of the string.";
```

Edit: and one thing I'd forget about, depending on what your data is, you may want to use htmlspecialchars function on in before inserting it anywhere into your HTML DOM, if it's user-provided data, in order to avoid XSS attack.